# Why was President Troare of Mali 'furious' at the arrest of the Ivoirian Minister of Planning for embezzling funds?

Tags: africa, scandal, finance

In 1984, Thomas Sankara, a military officer, revolutionary activist and President of Burkina Faso, was elected as the President of CEAO, the Economic Community of West Africa. Under his administration the largest financial scandal in the organisations history broke out.

Mohammed Diawara, the Ivoirian minister of Planning,  was charged for embezzling 6.5 billion dollars of CEAO funds marked for famine relief. Sankara declared it was time 'to clean house' and put him on trial before a Popular Revolutionary Tribunal in Ouagadougou, the capital of Burkino Faso. He was convicted and imprisoned.

The Malian elite were incensed and their President, Moussa Troare, was said to be furious. This eventually led to Troare provoking a senseless border war with Burkino Faso in late 1985.

**Q. Whilst Mali and the Ivory Coast share a border, they are separate countries. Why then were the Malian elite, and in particular, the Malian President,enraged by the arrest of an official of the government of the Ivory Coast?**

Comment: Some background https://www.thomassankara.net/conference-de-presse-du-president-du-faso-lors-des-journees-de-solidarite-des-jeunesses-de-la-ceao-6-decembre-1985/

Comment: More background https://search.proquest.com/openview/e772a00092ab52f3940b21a044d14c57/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=1820943

Comment: While I really enjoyed researching the history of W. Africa (something that isn't often taught at school!) I hope that I'm not just repeating what is obvious in my answer.  If you have done research on this already it would help if you linked to the sources (like the two I mentioned in comments) It is good to know what you have already read to avoid answers that merely repeat what you already have found out.

Comment: @JamesK: My research is in the background of my question. Moreover, the question was on what the sources didn't make explicit. Thus if an answer sticks to answering the question rather than beating about the bush then they're unlikely to repeat what I already know.

Comment: Yes.  But please read [ask].  Including sources to what you already know gets you better answers! If we don't know the sources, how are we to know what they do and don't make explicit. However I hope you'll agree that my answer below doesn't beat around any bushes.

Comment: @JamesK: No,  I've been on this site for some time and and there's no need to be patronising.

Comment: You have been on this and other SE sites for a while, so your questions should be models of "show research effort, be useful and clear"  This question suggests significant prior research: Mohammed Diawara is hardly a political celebrity! So the question is useful and clear (+1)  But you choose not to show research effort, even though it exists.  My actual purpose is to illustrate to new users how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 3):

Because the [Malian President and his wife were personally implicated in the affair](https://search.proquest.com/openview/e772a00092ab52f3940b21a044d14c57/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=1820943).

Mariam Traoré was herself a prominent businesswoman and had extensive financial dealings with the "Bank of Africa-Mali" which had been set up by Diawara, with funds taken from the Communaute Economique De L'afrique De L'ouest.

So the arrest and imprisonment of Diawara was not only an extraterritorial act, it was an attack on the business associates (and probably personal friend) of the Traoré family. And hence an attack and insult to the Malian President himself.  And thus he was enraged.